# Error while calculating maximum value in a series

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, filtering, pivot-table

I have a long series of numeric values. I want to find the maximum and minimum values of that series. I have used MIN and MAX functions to obtain the correct output but my series contains some `0` (zero) values so I used filter to find the maximum and minimum of that series excluding `0`.

When I filter `0` from the series and calculate maximum and minimum it shows correct minimum value but the maximum value of the series is changed.

Why has the maximum value changed while I have only filtered out `0` from the series?

Comment: Thanks Andre,I have already tried the procedure you described. The max value is not same in the filtered and non-filtered series.

Comment: I have analyzed the problem and the root cause is as follow:
The filter operation of MS EXCEL can handle only 10000 values. When we use filter on a series which has more than 10000 values it takes only first 10000 values and do further operation(calculating min,max,.. etc) on that.

Answer (score 1):

A PivotTable is not subject to the 10K limitation that a filter is. Max of Series in Σ Values should show the result you require.

Comment: Yes. I understand that the limitation of filter is 10K.